# Dead Hard Drive cannot mount

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, ssd, luks

I'm running ubuntu 20, and the SSD that died was running ubuntu 18.04. It was LUKS encrypted and suddenly died. I was able to access grub for a short amount of time but I no longer can. On my ubuntu 20 machine I'm unable to mount it, see it on fdisk and fsck says this:

```
sudo fsck /dev/sda
fsck from util-linux 2.34
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
fsck.ext2: No medium found while trying to open /dev/sda

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid     ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an  ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the   superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

`sudo cryptsetup open /dev/sda luksrecoverytarget --type luks Device /dev/sda doesn't exist or access denied.`

Finnix says that its able to see the partition but I still cannot mount it or even unlock it. I have little hope in saving it at this point, but I need help its the last 18 months of my work, no backups.

Comment: There's no point trying to `fsck` on an encrypted block device (instead of its container). Not really sure if there's anything left you can do if you can't even open/unlock it...(it's pretty much the point of encryption)

Comment: @tomyan of-course there is.   As is stated on almost every daya recovery type post - use ddrescue or somilar to one the underlying disk - as much as possible.  If you can do that (even with multiple passes and tricks like refrigeratong the disk - and more dangerous ones) you will have a stable /dev/sda you can likely unlock. Once you can unlock it you can attempt further recovery.

Comment: In fact, with the no medium found error, instead of expecting ddrescue et. al. would just run, I'd rather ask whether this is a portable SSD. If fortunate enough it could be just the enclosure that is fried or so.

Comment: Its an internal disk, I was able to cool it down and see it on the disks. I see all the partitions, however I'm getting an error with (udisks-error-quark, 0) when attempting the password.